# Cocos2d Scaling Issue

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, scaling, gitignore, cclabelttf

I am running a Cocos2d v3 game on xcode 6. After making some changes like adding more nodes in the code and cleaning the build. The scaling of the images and CCLabelTTF changed on a physical device to significantly smaller. After not figuring out the problem. I just used git reset --hard to go to the previous build, however this didn't change the problem. My theory is that something from the git ignore file is causing the problem. I don't know if it is the derived data or what.The first image is correctly sized.The second image is the incorrectly scaling. I'm most confused why after resetting to the previous commit the problem still exist. Thanks in advance for any help.

[image: Correctly Sized]

[image: Incorrectly Sized]